# django-jqgrid: how to settup the given example

Tags: django, jqgrid

I want to try [`django-jqgrid`](https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid) but the steps given as an example in the [`README.md`](https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid/blob/master/README.md) file are not clear enough. In particular step 4, which reads *Configure `jgrid` to use the defined urls.*, is too vague.

In what file the javascript code snippet given in the instruction should be put? Is an HTML template needed? More detailed steps would help.

[`django-jqgrid-demo`](https://bitbucket.org/romildo/django-jqgrid-demo) is a small demo application for `django-jqgrid` I am writing. The initial goal is to present data from a model in a tabular format, with sorting and filtering. So I defined the model class, the grid class, the viewer functions and the urls by following the steps in the `django-jqgrid` documentation (except for step 4). What is missing is a template for presenting the data. Any help on how to complete it is welcome.

Comment: You should put the JS snippet where you would like to use jqgrid, that may be in a template. Are you confused about where to put the javascript or about the URL's or both?

Comment: @Gerry Probably the problem as that I have just started learning JS and I still have a long way to go. I am hoping it is possible to use `django-jqgrid` without that knowledge. More detailed steps would help. For now I just want to use it to present data from a model in a tabular format, with sorting and filtering.